# awk in bash shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am using `awk` function for pattern matching. If `awk` contains operator sign such as ++ or -- it will give me error for searching.

For example during searching

4) search_book
Title: C++ Programming in 21 Days
Author:

0 records found

however without the C++(actually without the ++, cause if i type C, i will still get the result)

4) search_book
Title:  Programming in 21 Days
Author:

C++ Programming in 21 Days, Hacker Jane,$30.60,18,10

C++ Programming in 21 Days, J. D. Edwards,$50.03,15,10

C++ Programming in 21 Days, Paul Thompson,$45.00,18,10

3 records found

This is `awk` coding

`awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '$1 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' BookDB.txt`

Update:
I have been trying for hours, but i still cannot solve the problem,if i want to add a new line called "Book is not found" at the bottom when 0 record is found, how do i do that?

How do i make it to be case insensitive also?

```
     awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '{ if($1 == search) {printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; i++ } else {printf "Book not found"} }END {printf "%d records found\n", i}' BookDB.txt
```

This give me things like

```
Book not found  
Book not found 
c++ programming in 21 days 
Book not found
```

This does not show the "book not found" message

```
 if [ "$title" != "" ] && [ "$author" = "" ] ; then  
 awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '{ if($1 == search) {printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; i++ } else {printf "Book not found"} }END {printf "%d records found\n", i}' BookDB.txt 
 if [ "$i" < 1 ]; then
 echo -n "Book not found"
 fi
```

Comment: `+` is a [regex operator/special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), meaning one or more occurrences. You need to escape it using a `'\'`. `--` should not give you this problem, unless it is in `[xyz--pqa]` format.

Comment: awk is not part of bash; it's a completely unrelated language/tool. Unless your problem can only be generated when using bash in conjunction with awk, it's purely an awk question, not a bash question at all.

Comment: (Your follow-up question is an easy one to answer, by the way -- at its core, it's caused by putting the if/else statement into the block that's run on every line, not into the END block. However, amending additional questions into your question is not kosher here; it's not atypical to see a mod rolling such edits back).

Answer (score 3):

`$1 ~ search` treats the variable `search` as a regular expression.  If you don't want that, you can use the `index` function which searches for literal strings, not regexes:

```
$ title='C++ Programming in 21 Days'
$ awk  -F: -v search="$title" '(index($1, search) != 0) { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' BookDB.txt 
C++ Programming in 21 Days,  Hacker Jane,$30.60,18,10
C++ Programming in 21 Days,  J. D. Edwards,$50.03,15,10
C++ Programming in 21 Days,  Paul Thompson,$45.00,18,10
3 records found
```

`index($1, search)` returns the location of the string `search` inside the string `$1`.  If `search` is not found, then `index` returns `0`.

I changed `-F':'` to `-F:`.  This works because `:` is not a shell-active character.  There is no harm in quoting it but the quotes are not necessary.

#### Updated Question

To get `book not found`:

```
$ awk  -F: -v search="$title" '(index($1, search) != 0) { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { if (i) printf "%d records found\n", i ; else print "Book not found";}' BookDB.txt
```

If you have GNU awk (gawk), then adding case-insensitivity is easy:

```
awk  -F: -v search="$title" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;} (index($1, search) != 0) { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { if (i) printf "%d records found\n", i ; else print "Book not found";}' BookDB.txt
```

If it makes it easier to understand, here is the same code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk  -F: -v search="$title" '
BEGIN{
    IGNORECASE=1;
}

(index($1, search) != 0){
    i++;
    printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
}

END{
    if (i) 
        printf "%d records found\n", i ;
    else
        print "Book not found";
}
' BookDB.txt
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Hi i update my question, appreciate if you can help me out. I am new to bash, so i am trying to play around

Comment: @user3848196, updating a question in a way that changes its meaning after you already have an answer is not kosher here. If you have another question, it should be asked independently.